# Generating shortcut links to sections of an alphabetized document in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm working on a stylesheet to convert an alphabetized XML book index to XHTML. As part of this process, I have to:

1. Add anchor tags to the first entry of each letter.
2. Create a line at the top with each letter in the alphabet, each with a link to the correct anchor.
3. Have the links at the top be different if there is no corresponding anchor. (For instance, the link might have an extra title attribute.)

Here's a simplified example of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<index>
    <heading>I'm an index</heading>
    <primaryEntry>Andy</primaryEntry>
    <primaryEntry>Bob</primaryEntry>
    <primaryEntry>Jimmy</primaryEntry>
    <primaryEntry>Johnny</primaryEntry>
    <primaryEntry>Josephine</primaryEntry>
    <primaryEntry>Zed</primaryEntry>
</index>
```

Here's the intended output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html><head>Index</head><body>
    <h1>I'm an index</h1>
    <p><a href="#A">A</a>  <a href="#B">B</a>  <a href="#C" title="I go nowhere">C</a>  <a href="#D" title="I go nowhere">D</a>  ... <a href="#J">J</a> ... <a href="#Y" title="I go nowhere">Y</a>  <a href="#Z">Z</a>  </p>
    <a name="A"></a><p>Andy</p>
    <a name="B"></a><p>Bob</p>
    <a name="J"></a><p>Jimmy</p>
    <p>Johnny</p>
    <p>Josephine</p>
    <a name="Z"></a><p>Zed</p>
</body></html>
```

This was my attempt, which won't run. (See comment.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="atict" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="index">
        <xsl:element name="html">
            <xsl:element name="head">Index</xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="body">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="heading">
        <xsl:element name="h1">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:variable name="alphabet" select="tokenize('A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z', ' ')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$alphabet">
                <xsl:sort select="."/>
                <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:variable name="letter" select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="//primaryEntry[starts-with(., $letter)]"> <!--Error: We can no longer see the document from this context -->
                        <xsl:attribute name="title" select="'I go nowhere'"></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="primaryEntry">
        <xsl:variable name="first_letter" select="upper-case(substring(normalize-space(.), 1, 1))" />
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::primaryEntry[starts-with(upper-case(normalize-space(.)), $first_letter)])">
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$first_letter" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This approach works for requirements 1 and 2, but I'm not sure if 3 is possible using this approach. Once I'm evaluating a node set in for-each, there's no "popping back out" to check to see if there's a corresponding element in the XML document. I'm fairly new to XSLT and I strongly suspect I'm thinking about this whole problem backwards, but I'm at a loss about where to go from here.

Comment: "*2. Create a line at the top with each letter in the alphabet,*"Why not create links to existing letters only?

Comment: Haha, exactly my first impulse, but it has to match what was produced by the system before. God knows what the people in charge of style were thinking. I might try to convince them to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ....

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0"  doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
            encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="letter" match="primaryEntry" use="substring(.,1,1)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="." />
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Sample Corporation #1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>I'm an index</h1>
    <p>
     <xsl:for-each select="'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'">
     <a href="#{.}">
        <xsl:if test="not( key('letter',.,$main-doc))">
         <xsl:attribute name="title">I go nowhere</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
     </a>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </p> 
    <xsl:for-each-group select="index/primaryEntry" group-by="substring(.,1,1)">
      <a name="{current-grouping-key()}"></a>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="primaryEntry">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... which yields ...  (using Saxon-HE 9.5.1.1N from Saxonica)

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sample Corporation #1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I'm an index</h1>
        <p>
            <a href="#A">A</a>
            <a href="#B">B</a>
            <a href="#C" title="I go nowhere">C</a>
            <a href="#D" title="I go nowhere">D</a>
            <a href="#E" title="I go nowhere">E</a>
            <a href="#F" title="I go nowhere">F</a>
            <a href="#G" title="I go nowhere">G</a>
            <a href="#H" title="I go nowhere">H</a>
            <a href="#I" title="I go nowhere">I</a>
            <a href="#J">J</a>
            <a href="#K" title="I go nowhere">K</a>
            <a href="#L" title="I go nowhere">L</a>
            <a href="#M" title="I go nowhere">M</a>
            <a href="#N" title="I go nowhere">N</a>
            <a href="#O" title="I go nowhere">O</a>
            <a href="#P" title="I go nowhere">P</a>
            <a href="#Q" title="I go nowhere">Q</a>
            <a href="#R" title="I go nowhere">R</a>
            <a href="#S" title="I go nowhere">S</a>
            <a href="#T" title="I go nowhere">T</a>
            <a href="#U" title="I go nowhere">U</a>
            <a href="#V" title="I go nowhere">V</a>
            <a href="#W" title="I go nowhere">W</a>
            <a href="#X" title="I go nowhere">X</a>
            <a href="#Y" title="I go nowhere">Y</a>
            <a href="#Z">Z</a>
        </p>
        </a name="A">
        <p>Andy</p>
        </a name="B">
        <p>Bob</p>
        </a name="J">
        <p>Jimmy</p>
        <p>Johnny</p>
        <p>Josephine</p>
        </a name="Z">
        <p>Zed</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This got me through. I was having trouble using key() in my experiments but I didn't really understand why until I realized there's a three-argument form. Setting a variable back to the outer context was exactly what I needed.